# EF Core - return null for entity with foreign key with id = 0

Tags: c#, odata, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using a database from a 3rd party (only have read access to it) with a nullable column that is a foreign key to another table:

```
Person.Id    1-*    PatientFile.PatientId
PatientFile.PrescDocID    0...1 - 0...1    Person.Id
```

I'm using an OData clone (https://github.com/trenoncourt/AutoQueryable) to fetch related data when adding to the URL: ?select=*

The problem is that the nullable column (Person.Id) sometimes contains the id 0 instead of null. This means that the property PrescDoc is presented in my JSON response as

```
"prescDoc": {
   "surName": null,
   "firstName": null,
   "isNaturalPerson": null,
   "birthDate": null,
   "id": 0
}
```

while it should be:

```
"prescDoc": null
```

Is there a way to configure EF Core to set the property prescDoc on PatientFile to null if the id of the prescDoc object or the PatientFile.PrescDocId id 0?

Version I'm using:

- ASP.NET Core 2.1.1
- EF Core 2.1.1
- Database running on MSSQL 2008R2
- Webserver running on Windows Server 2016

Comment: if property `x` is nullable and is 0, then you add a check `if( x == 0) {x = null;}`

Comment: I'm using AutoQueryable, so I'm not able to change the LINQ query. I'm asking if this is configurable on the DbContext or on the Entity model itself. Or on AutoMapper.

Comment: I’m not sure about it, you can try ‘int? x = null;’ in model class.

Comment: The id is 0 in the database, so EF fetches the id as 0 and overrides the default 'null' that I would set on the property in the model

Answer (score 1):

Some other options:

In your entity class, you can override the getter:

```
private int? prescDocID;
public int? PrescDocID
{
    get => prescDocID == 0 ? default : prescDocID;
    set => prescDocID = value;
}
```

Or, you can use a custom JsonConverter to control it during serialization:

```
public class ZeroToNullConverter : JsonConverter<int?>
{
    public override int? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, int? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        reader.Value as int? == 0 ? default : reader.Value as int?;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, int? value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        writer.WriteValue(value == 0 ? default : value); 
}
```

Then:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ZeroToNullConverter))]
public int? PrescDocID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoQueryable, according to their docs, you can override the Get method. So you can override with a Select so that the Person object being constructed can have the prescDoc prop null if the value of the id is 0:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AutoQueryable]
    public IQueryable<Person> Get([FromServices] myDbContext dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.Person.Select(p => new Person() { 
           --other props go here--, 
           prescDoc = p.prescDoc.Id == 0 ? null: p.prescDoc 
           } 
           );
    }
}
```